# Mockito return value when throw exception

Tags: java, spring, junit, mockito

Any tips how to mock a method and return a value when it throws a specific exception using Mockito?

I am looking for something like this:

```
doReturn(0).whenCall(employees.calculateSalary()).and().Whenthrows(ExceptionX.class)
```

Returning a value when the method throws `ExceptionX`.

Comment: That's not really mocking. In order for the method to throw an exception, you have to invoke it. If you invoke the real method instead of mocking the method and modifying its behavior, you're not using a mock.

Comment: You cannot do two things, returning a value and throwing an exception, at the same time.

Comment: Either return value or throw exception - how would you expect for this to work in the same time ??? If you want to return something if there has been exception throw, well use try-catch for this...

Comment: I am not trying to throw an exception, All I want is to react to the exception when it is thrown.
I want to return a value when a method throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return value and throw exception at the same time. 
If you know when that method throws exception and when it returns value, then you can create two separate mocked objects. One mocked object would have state which causes exception and another mocked object which returns value, and use those objects separately for your test cases.